# Dealing with strictFunctionTypes and required fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I've run into a problem with my dynamic data tables. They're a series of configurations for each field. Everything has certain fields (id, createdAt, updatedAt, etc), but some fields are object specific.

I've reproduced this as best as I can below.

This all works as long as **everything** in UserData or PostData is optional. But we know letting a users email be undefined is completely pointless, in this context.

```js
// The fields we know all objects will have
type RawData = { id: number; }

// The fields of a specific type of object
type UserData = RawData & { email: string, name: string };
type PostData = RawData & { name: string }

// A field config, for dynamic tables or similiar
type Config = {
  getValue: (data: RawData) => string;
}

const ConfigMap: Record<string, Config> = {
  // A field that is only valid for users
  USERNAME: {
    entity: ['USERS'],
    getValue: (data: UserData) => ''
  },
  // A field that is valid for either
  NAME: {
    entity: ['USERS', 'POSTS'],
    getValue: (data: UserData | PostData) => ''
  }
}
```

The problem is `strictFunctionTypes` doesn't like this. As long as everything is optional, it's fine. But the second I require something it breaks down.

Is this solvable without breaking strictFunctionTypes?

Comment: You could use `getValue: (data: UserData & PostData) => string;` in `Config`, then your `const ConfigMap` would validate. But you'd have a hard time calling the function.

Comment: You might have to sprinkle in some `any`s or use type assertions, or you could make `Config` a union of the possible `getValue` signatures, possibly discriminated on the `entity` property (since that appears to be what you actually want)

Comment: If you want a specific `Config` type then it needs to be the union of every possible *set* of entities in your system, which can get combinatorically crazy... but it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJqDDm).  Does that meet your needs or does it break somewhere?  If it works I can write up an answer; if not, what is the problem?